# Openshift rails application no such file error on rake:db:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I created RoR application in Openshift. Cloned it to local machine, there all was fine. But when I tried to move things I've done to server, including DataBase, on loading my DB scheme (rake db:scheme:load) from app-root/repo, I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - 
/var/lib/openshift/54a37ee65973cacb4b000138/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration'
/var/lib/openshift/54a37ee65973cacb4b000138/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/openshift/54a37ee65973cacb4b000138/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
...
```

There is more, I can provide all, I just don't think it necessary.

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my-database
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my-database
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my-database
  username: my-username
  password: my-password
  host: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

EDIT: Just noticed that when I push my app it's status stacks on Deploying. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Please double check that your database.yml is in the right folder `config/database.yml` and does not have any typos in the name.

Comment: It is. I think it's some openshift thing. May be I start rake from wrong directory or something like that. Just checked from console to be sure, file app-root/repo/config/database.yml is on it's place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was editing wrong database.yml. In my project i have one in config and one in .openshift/config. In quickstart app from scratch 1st one only contains path to second, I probably removed this string when was configuring my db 1st time. So put this string back, move DB configuration to .openshift folder, and thats it, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this database.yml configuration for whatever server type you are using (https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example/blob/master/.openshift/config/database.yml), and you can also try using this quickstart (https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example) and it should automatically run rake db:migrate when you do a git push, which will run all of your migrations for you and update your database.

Comment: I replaced config with one from Your link, no changes.